# How to get value from selected item in treeview in PyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I'm learning PyGtk. I have a simple treeview with 1 column, I get items for that treeview from list.

How to get value of selected item in treeview?

Comment: PS: Don't forget to accept (by clicking on the "right" to the left of the answer) my answer if it suits you. Thanks !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may use the  [gtk.TreeView.get_selection()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-selection) method to get the `gtk.TreeSelection`.

Next, you should use the [gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--get-selected-rows) method to get the TreeModel (the ListStore) and the selected items
 paths.

Then, you can use the [gtk.TreeModel.get_iter()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html#method-gtktreemodel--get-iter) in order to get the iter from the path (returned by the `gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows()` method).

Finally, you may use the [gtk.TreeModel.get_value()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html#method-gtktreemodel--get-value) method to get the value corresponding to the column and the iter previously recovered.

Example :

```
def onSelectionChanged(tree_selection) :
    (model, pathlist) = tree_selection.get_selected_rows()
    for path in pathlist :
        tree_iter = model.get_iter(path)
        value = model.get_value(tree_iter,0)
        print value

listStore = gtk.ListStore(int)
treeview = gtk.TreeView()
treeview.set_model(listStore)
tree_selection = treeview.get_selection()
tree_selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
tree_selection.connect("changed", onSelectionChanged)
```